# Calling webservice with NTLM authentication

Tags: apex

Calling webservice with NTLM authentication and getting error 'System.CalloutException: Web service callout failed: Unexpected element. Parser was expecting element 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/:Envelope' but found ':HTML'' I am able to access the webservice through browser but not through apex.

Comment: Your Apex Code is expecting a SOAP message, but the server is returning a HTML page. The server has to be able to speak SOAP in order to communicate through that interface. Maybe you meant to use the REST interface instead?

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps the authentication is failing and the page is returning HTML as an "error" page.

Update your question with more details - how did you upload your WSDL? Have you used [SoapUI](http://www.soapui.org) to test your callouts and review the results?

This is what I do ***before*** I try to debug my SOAP callouts on the Salesforce APEX environment.